# TypeScript src module imports aren't compiled correctly in dist

Tags: typescript, module, tsconfig

I'm developing a REST API in TS that, summarized, is structured in the following way:

```
├── dist
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── library.js
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── library.ts
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── .gitignore
```

The issue that I'm facing is that module imports in index.ts are not being compiled correctly in index.js, as a reference:

index.ts

```
import { someFunc } from '../library.ts';
```

index.js

```
import { someFunc } from '../library.ts';
```

If the file were compiled correctly, index.js's imports would be:

```
import { someFunc } from '../library.js';
```

I think it's safe to say that the issue is related to tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  }
}
```

I have tried to play around with tsconfig.json but did not end up in finding a satisfying solution,  I would also like to keep the module type set to `NodeNext` rather then `ESNext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsc` [does not touch the import path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/theory.html#module-specifiers-are-not-transformed) (a.k.a. "module specifier"), *including the potential file extension*:

> the module specifier (the string `from` which you `import`, or pass to `require`) is always emitted as-written.

You have to write the *final* file extension:

```
// In index.ts
import { someFunc } from '../library.js'; // Final .js file extension
```

...even if it means

> strangeness of seeing output file extensions in input files

Comment: Is such approach considered to a _good practice_ when it comes to production level code or is it a _better practice_ to use different values for `module` key such as `ESNext`?

Comment: It is the way tsc works. `module` key in `tsconfig.json` only changes the `import` syntax, but _not the path_. As soon as you use ESM (with `.mts` or `"type": "module"` in `package.json`), you must include file extension, and above answer applies. Otherwise, we can omit the extension, which avoids this strangeness. I have added a link to the docs, but for some reason I can no longer find the original one which I found even more explicit.